# Given Hermitian matrices, can we construct a matrix with a particular singular value decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we are given $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$. Does there exists a way in which we can use $M_1$ and $M_2$ to construct a matrix $M$ whose left singular vectors are eigenvectors of $M_1$, and whose right singular vectors are eigenvectors of $M_2$, such that the dependence of $M$ on $M_1$ and $M_2$ is explicit (i.e. $M = f(M_1, M_2)$ where $f$ is some well-behaved function).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no".

Assume the eigenvalues of $M_1$ are single. Let $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n$ be the eigenvectors of $M_1.$ Then $v_i\perp v_j$ for $i\neq j.$ Assume $Mv_i=\mu_iv_i $ for $1\le i\le n.$ Then $M^*v_i=\bar{\mu}_iv_i,$ which means the left eigenvectors coincide with right eigenvectors.